# Json object returns with brackets

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse an Json object and it has this data:

```
"ingredients":["White bread","Bratwurst","Onions","Tomato ketchup","Mustard","Curry powder"]
```

When I return the value, the textview prints this :

```
[White bread,Bratwurst,Onions,Tomato ketchup,Mustard,Curry powder]
```

I want to remove the brackets but I cant. I'm doing this so far:

```
List<String> mIngredientArray = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray ingredients = null;
Sandwich mSandwich = new Sandwich();

    ingredients = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("ingredients");
       for(int i=0; i<ingredients.length();i++){
            mIngredientArray.add(ingredients.getString(i));
        }
mSandwich.setIngredients(mIngredientArray);
```

The textview code:

```
ingredientsTV.setText(sandwich.getIngredients().toString());
```

But doesnt works. Any idea about how to solve it?

REQUIRED OUTPUT:-

```
White bread, Bratwurst, Onions, Tomato ketchup, Mustard, Curry powder
```

Comment: that `[]` is JSON notation of arrays

Comment: what do you mean by `doesnt work`?

Comment: Aren't you passing ingredients from one array to another?

Comment: What is your print statement?

Comment: The result depend on how you print the array.

Comment: The output is [White bread,Bratwurst,Onions,Tomato ketchup,Mustard,Curry powder] but I need only White bread,Bratwurst,Onions,Tomato ketchup,Mustard,Curry powder

Comment: @Coeus can you paste the code where you set this value to the textview

Comment: @ヅfix I updated the question

Comment: @Coeus you can use regex, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used this line of code to solve my problem:

```
ingredientsTv.setText(sandwich.getIngredients().toString().replace("[","").replace("]",""));
```

When I tried to use ReplaceAll, the IDE said that I need to use 24 as minimunSdkVersion but I was using 16 so that's the reason I use replace instead of ReplaceAll. And it works finally.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove the brackets, you can use regex like this

```
strIngredients = sandwich.getIngredients().toString();
strIngredients = strIngredients.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
ingredientsTV.setText(strIngredients);
```

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that only works when minimunVersion> 24 and I'm use 16 as minimunVersion

Comment: @Coeus regular expressions are not dependent on minimunVersion, have you used the same format above

Comment: I mean, replaceAll only works when minimunVersion > 24

Comment: as i said the method `replaceAll` has no dependency on android's minimumVersion, it is a method from `String` class in `package java.lang`, can you the code you tested and the output you got for minimunVersion> 24

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace the bracket characters as suggested, but that doesn’t strike me as the most direct solution. You need to specify how the List object is converted to a string — something like:

```
String.join(“, “, mIngredientArray)
```